# How can i process value get from checkbox by JS then do something with it in Java action?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, checkbox

I have a checkbox like this in JSP

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" name="checkBox"/>
```

In JS file I wrote a function to set data for a variable when checkbox be clicked

```
$("checkBox").change(function(){
var checkBox= 0;
if(this.checked) {
    checkBox= 1;
} else {
    checkBox= 0;
}
})
```

Then in Java action class I want to do something when checkbox be clicked

```
if(bean.getCheckBox == 1) {//do something}
```

But it's not working. Please help me fix this one !  thanks

Comment: I think you are a bit confused, first you must send your value to your controller by some means for example ajax or by sending the value in a form, and in the backend part you must catch this value for example with a reques.getParameter ("checkboxname") to use it

Answer (score 0):

The `var checkBox` is a client-side JavaScript *local variable* and its value will only ever be visible inside the `change` event listener; your action class which (I'm assuming) is a server side component will not have access to this value.

Your action class should instead check for the value of the `checkBox` *request parameter* which comes from the `value` attribute.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" name="checkBox" value="1" />
```

Then in your action class you'll have something like:

```
if ("1".equals(request.getParameter("checkBox"))) {
    ...
}
```

Or, you can also simply do a null-check and not check for any specific value.

```
if (request.getParameter("checkBox") != null) {
    ...
}
```

If you're using some framework bean, you'll use something like below depending on the bean's `checkBox` variable's data type.

```
if ("1".equals(bean.getCheckBox())) { // String
    ...
}

// or
if (bean.getCheckBox() != null) { // String or Integer
    ...
}

// or
if (bean.getCheckBox() == 1) { // int primitive
    ...
}
```

The value to check for still comes from the `value` attribute above.